# Arduino List sort - how do I implement the comparitor?

Tags: linked-list, arduino, quicksort, arduino-c++

I'm using List ([https://github.com/nkaaf/Arduino-List](https://stackoverflow.com)) in my Arduino program. I need to be able to re-sort the list as the data is updated. The documentation indicates that the sort() method is inherited from the AbstractList< T > Class. ([https://nkaaf.github.io/Arduino-List/html/class_abstract_list.html](https://stackoverflow.com)).

As far as I can see the sort algorithm takes a comparitor ([https://nkaaf.github.io/Arduino-List/html/class_abstract_list.html#a6f18cfb85d7ffd22123cf85d38cad85d](https://stackoverflow.com)) with signature

`int(*)(const void *, const void *) compFunc`

However I can't find any examples of how to write `compFunc()` for custom types.
Also I can't find any documentation or specs beyond the signature e.g. how should the return value be calculated.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have tried writing compFunc() like:

```
    int compFunc(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return (a.getValue() < b.getValue());
  }
```

The method `getValue()` is implemented on all the classes that are stored in the list but I get a compile error:

`Compilation error: request for member 'getVal' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'const void*'`

I have also tried replacing `const void *` with the actual Type of a & b but I get:

`Compilation error: passing 'const MyClass' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

I have also tried without the `const` keyword and I get:

`Compilation error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(MyClass*, MyClass*)' to 'int (*)(const void*, const void*)' [-fpermissive]`